# How to Mount an NTFS Formatted SD Card with pmount (or other tool)?

Tags: mount, ntfs, sd-card, fuse

I wrote a script which transfers automatically pictures from the SD card (taken with a digital camera) to the harddrive and takes care of putting them in a subdirectory in the main pictures folder and renaming them.

The script does that via udev (execute script as soon as an SD card with a certain label is inserted) and pmount (mount the SD card). The actual transfer and the renaming is not interesting for this problem.

pmount works well with vfat formatted cards, but it doesn't with NTFS, which is the cameras choice of filesystem. I get the following error message:

```
Error opening '/dev/sdX1' read-write NTFS signature is missing. 
Failed to mount '/dev/sdX1': Invalid argument 
The device '/dev/sdX1' doesn't seem to have a valid NTFS. 
Maybe the wrong device is used? Or the whole disk instead of a partition (e.g. /dev/sda, not /dev/sda1)? Or the other way around?
```

I tried several options of pmount (read-only, specific filesystem, ...), but still it doesn't work. On the other hand, the card is shown in Thunar and Nemo and clicking on the entry there mounts the card without any problem. The card is then mounted like this:

```
/dev/sdX1 on /media/USER/NAME type fuseblk (ro,nosuid,nodev,relatime,user_id=0,group_id=0,default_permissions,allow_other,blksize=4096,uhelper=udisks2)
```

Any idea how pmount can do the the same, or what other tool I can use? Or how Thunar or Nemo do the mounting? Of course creating a /etc/fstab entry is possible, but that's not elegant.

Answer (score 0):

Just after posting this question, I found the answer on StackExchange. Instead of `pmount LABEL` I need to use `udiskctl mount -b BLOCKDEVICE`. Replace this in the script and adapt the udev rule and it works.